# AKKA classic multi interface connections

Tags: akka, akka-tcp

I am using AKKA classic and still have to use java 6 on some machines, so I am limited on choice. I am using Netty TCP.

Many of our machines are multi interface machines, and at some point I will need to connect on more than one at a time.

Based on what I know, I think I would have to create a second ActorSystem on the second interface. UDP seems to work differently than TCP in this regard, as you don't specify an interface and it listens to them all, from what I can tell.

What is the expected way to do this?